# Java: How to view icon overlapping each other

Tags: java, image, swing

```
JLabel l1 = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( ... ) ) ;    
JLabel l2 = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( ... ) ) ;
l1.setBounds( 0, 0, 50, 50 ) ;
l2.setBounds( 10, 10, 50, 50 ) ;
```

That occupy some of the place of l1. If I want to view all the l1 ignoring l2, what should I write ?

Comment: by overlaping you meaning that part for one Icon is covered by another ???,

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of:

- A `JLayeredPane`.  See [How to Use Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).
- A custom layout.  See [Creating a Custom Layout Manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).
- Custom painting.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Could fulfill the requirement.

Here is a screenshot from the tutorial on layered panes.

[image: LayeredPane Demo]